# UNCLAIMED in lshw command and how to fix?

Tags: networking, drivers, 15.10, hardware, devices

this is a part of  lshw command output. what means of UNCLAIMED and how to fix ?

```
   description: Computer
width: 64 bits
capabilities: smbios-2.7 vsyscall32


 *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-generic UNCLAIMED
          physical id: 1
          bus info: parisc@1
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 0
          size: 7896MiB
     *-cpu
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4702MQ CPU @ 2.20GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 2
          bus info: cpu@0
          size: 2526MHz
          capacity: 3200MHz
          width: 64 bits
```

...

```
   *-serial UNCLAIMED
         description: SMBus
         product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
         version: 05
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:b5719000-b57190ff ioport:6040(size=32)
```

Comment: I don't know. My guess would be that Ubuntu does not use it, e.g. because it has no driver/kernel module for it.

Comment: Thanks bus How can i find  driver for those devices?

Comment: As I said, it was just a guess, it may be wrong. No idea.